# Blocks expanding issue with z-index

Tags: javascript, css, animation, z-index

I have a blocks overview, and when you click on one block it expands.
When clicking outside the expanded block, or on the "x", it resizes back to the default size.

But there are two issues I don't know how to solve.

When you click on a block with Chrome/Safari, the z-index updates a millisecond too late and it doesn't look smooth. (Firefox on MAC is okay when expanding.)

When it's expanded and goes back, the z-index needs to be higher than the other blocks. So, when it goes to normal the site looks a lot better.

So, when clicking, it should add `z-index:2;` and when it's resizing back to default size the `z-index` needs to be `1` so its higher than the others ( which are 0) but, when another is expanding, that needs to be the highest.

Can anyone help me with this? I'd rather use some JS magic for this, maybe inline style?

I also made a jsfiddle to show what I mean.
https://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/sp7vbtok/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">    
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="g-inner" style="background-image:url(https://placekitten.com/350/350);">
            <div class="g-item"><img src="/some-png-img.png" height="175" width="175" /></div>
            <div class="g-more">Bla bla bla.</div>
            <div class="g-close">x</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".grid-item").on("click", function(){
    $(".grid-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
$(".g-close").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".grid-item").removeClass("active");
});
```

CSS

```
.grid{width:875px; margin:20px auto;}
.grid:after {content:''; display:block; clear:both;}
.grid-item{width:175px; height:175px;}

.g-more{display:none; position:absolute; top:175px; height:175px; width:175px; transition:all 1s ease-in-out; opacity:0; padding:20px;}
.active .g-more{opacity:1; display:block;}

.grid-item{float:left; width:175px; height:175px; background:#ddd; color:#fff;}
.grid-item:before{display:block; padding:0;}
.grid-item-wide, .grid-item-wide .g-inner, .grid-item-wide .g-item{width:350px; height:175px;}

.g-inner{cursor:pointer; overflow:hidden; z-index:1; width:175px; height:175px; transition:all 1s ease-in-out; -webkit-background-size:cover; -moz-background-size:cover; -o-background-size:cover; background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:left 50%;}
.active .g-inner{width:350px; height:350px; position:relative; z-index:2; cursor:default;}
.open-left.active .g-inner{margin-left:-175px;}
.open-top.active .g-inner{margin-top:-175px;}

.g-item{width:175px; height:175px; position:relative;}

.g-close{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; right:-50px; bottom:-50px; width:50px; height:50px; line-height:50px; font-size:35px; display:none; opacity:0; text-align:center; transition:all 1s ease-in-out;}
.active .g-close{opacity:1; right:0; top:auto; bottom:0; z-index:5; display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use insted

```
 .active .g-inner {
        width:350px;
        height:350px;

    }
```

with `transform:scale` and `transform-origin` (-if you want set pivot x and y as top-left) like this:

```
 .active .g-inner {
        transform: scale(2);
        transform-origin: left top;

    }
```

its work fine for me

Comment: Hi Yosef, it works but I don't want to do it like that. It is scaling the text inside it too and I also have a wider and less high block which needs a different scale. I was hoping for a JS solution which adds some z-index.